# javascript function dodging the if statement and going straight for the gold

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have an if statement that I am trying to use to attack a problem with async functions, everything works great when it works however that take multiple refreshes. The page errors out several times then finally displays the color i need. Below is just an example but on the server side once the client connects, the server is dodging my if statement and goes straight for  function current(). Here is example of what its doing. I'd like to update the clients color based on colors from the server so if they chose the color green their choice comes back to the server, goes through a function and spits out a different color which then is sent back over to them, when it works. My issue is,  Im completely dodging the if statement.

```
function ijoined() {
do this();
do that();
after doing this and that();
decide();
}

Decideds what color to display 
function decide() {
  if (yellow !== null) {
     start();
    console.log('I started');
  } else {
    current();
    console.log('I already started');
  }
} 

First color displayed for client
function start() {
      yellow = 545;
 }

Current color
function current() {
    var color id = clients color;
    var time = current time;
  }
```

Comment: you need to declare yellow globally to these methods.

Comment: Yellow is always changing based on clients connected and selection. Its not illustrated here but yellow is actually a different value from a different client its constantly changing. Yellows value is a value from a sync function . But with several refreshes I get the right color.  I just want the if statement working.

Comment: Im not even calling the start function for this particular client. yet its still goes there no matter what.

Comment: This "code" looks like a bunch of syntax errors to me.

Comment: but if `yellow` is not in global scope then whatever values other methods assign to `yellow` will not be visible to `decide`

Comment: @gurvinder372 -- Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize what I understand you want to do:

- Have the client javascript generate a (random?) color and send it to the server
- Have the server modify the color, send it back to the client

I see a couple of problems here. Posting the entire codebase (client & server) you actually use would help tremendously with giving an answer.

First, you never seem to define the variable yellow, so when you get to

```
if (yellow !== null) {
    // ...
}
```

you run into a reference error.

Also, your variable names are invalid, they must not contain spaces.

```
color id
```

is not a valid variable name, as opposed to

```
color_id 
// or
colorId
```

Refer to https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers or https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp for a quick reference on valid variable names.

Also, your comments aren't really comments. You have to either prefix them with a double slash as such:

```
// This is a comment
This is a syntax error
```

or wrap them in /**/ as such:

```
/*
This is also a comment
that can span multiple lines
*/
```

Where does the communication with the server happen?
Unless you give me more to work with, unfortunately I can't help you.